# ClickOnce: Dependent Executable in manifest not installed

Tags: windows, installation, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce deployed application A that requires a third-Party executable B.exe. B.exe is referenced inside the Project A.
The application manifest contains `A.exe` as startup application. `A.exe.manifest` contains a dependency to `B.exe`.

All binaries and manifests and other required files are correctly deployed to IIS.

Upon executing the Application network-deployed for the first time, the Application is completely downloaded by ClickOnce. All required files appear in the ClickOnce Log File in this way:

```
[09:05:53] : Method Call : DownloadSingleFile called
[09:05:53] : DownloadQueueItem :  _sourceUri = http://localhost/A/1.0.0.0/B.exe,  _targetPath = C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\PT44L145.G7Y\6OXRRZ4O.RG4\B.exe
[09:05:53] : HttpWebRequest= Proxy.IsByPassed=True, ProxyUri=http://localhost/A/1.0.0.0/B.exe
[09:05:53] : HttpWebResponse=ResponseUri=http://localhost/A/1.0.0.0/B.exe
```

<strike>I don't know whether the file is correctly copied to `_targetPath` because the folder is deleted too fast.</strike>
The file is copied correctly to `_targetPath`.

After deploying A.exe is executed by ClickOnce from the Installation directory (something like `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\RZPET3XL.MDD\DP0VG7XH.MDZ\A.exe_f5309fcb4f74cdd0_0004.0003_07a7ad3d606fa838\`)

The directory `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\RZPET3XL.MDD\DP0VG7XH.MDZ\A.exe_f5309fcb4f74cdd0_0004.0003_07a7ad3d606fa838\` does not contain `B.exe` so the Third party process cannot be started. But it contains `B.exe.manifest`, `B.exe.config`, `B.cdf-ms` and all other files required by the application and contained in `A.exe.manifest`.

Why is B.exe not copied to the installation directory and how can i let it appear there?

// edit: I used Process Monitor and checked whether there was maybe a problem with opening the file or something other weird. There was none. There is not even an attempt to read B.exe from the deployment directory.

Comment: Have you checked it's publish status in the Properties > Publish > Application Files dialogue and ensured it is also set as Build Action = Content in the file properties within the main solution folder?

Comment: The click once manifest is built using mage.exe in a buildscript using the parameter `-FromDirectory`. The Properties->Publish Settings are completely untouched.

Comment: I touched the settings now, and included B.exe. Still no difference

Comment: I resolved it by workaround: I put B.exe in a zip File, deploy that and extract it on first launch.